# How to convert a dataframe column to a factor using rpy2?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, type-conversion, rpy2

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` in Python that I am converting to an R `data.frame` using `rpy2`. Some example setup code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    'col_2': [1, 2, 3],
    'col_3': [2.3, 5.4, 3.8]
})

pandas2ri.activate()
r_df = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)
```

`col_2` is full of integer values, and as expected, during conversion this is transformed into R's `int` atomic mode.  I can check the classes (which I understand to dictate which functions can be applied to the underlying objects) using the following:

```
r.sapply(r_df, r['class'])
```

However, this variable is actually nominal (an unordered categorical). As such, I need to convert this column into a factor.

In R I could easily do this via reassignment using something like:

```
r_df$col2 <- as.factor(r_df$col2)
```

However, I am unsure of the correct syntax using `rpy2`. I can access the column using the `rx2` accessor method and cast the column to a factor using `FactorVector`.

```
 col2 = robjects.vectors.FactorVector(r_df.rx2('col_2'))
```

However, I can't seem to reassign this back to the original dataframe. What is the best way to reassign this back to the original dataframe? And is there a better way to do this conversion? Thanks

#### Appended

I've managed to convert `col_2` to a `factor` using the code below, but it doesn't feel like an optimal answer, as I am having to look up all of the column names, find the index of the desired column using Python methods instead of R, and then use that for reassignment.

```
col_2_index = list(r_df.colnames).index('col_2')
col_2 = robjects.vectors.FactorVector(r_df.rx2('col_2'))
r_df[assessor_col_index] = col_2
```

Ideally, I'd like to see a reassignment method that doesn't rely on looking up the column index. However, my attempts before have thrown the following errors:

```
r_df['col_2'] = converted_col
TypeError: SexpVector indices must be integers, not str
```

or

```
r_df.rx2('col_2') = converted_col
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```